# Question closed as "already answered" pointing to another closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This page [Making a robust, resizable Swing Chess GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142686/making-a-robust-resizable-swing-chess-gui) is marked as closed "Too broad".

However, the page [Create a Chess board with JPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077322/create-a-chess-board-with-jpanel) is closed as a duplicate "alrteady answered" with the answer pointing to the question referred to above.

Now, the Chess GUI question appears to have been adopted by someone (I am not a SO expert BTW) and is useful but I can't help thinking that a closed question (duplicate) should not point to another closed question as the "already answered".

Just a thought about SO operation which Meta appears to be set up for.

Comment: *I can't help thinking that a closed question (duplicate) should not point to another closed question as the "already answered".* Why not? It does have two answers on it.

Comment: Because a closed question is closed whereas a question that is not closed is Open. An Open question is more useful. I juts wondered whether a closed Q might in fact be in a chain of (say) dup>dup>dup>broad>dup but at the end of the chain should be an open question. I would have an exception for questions that close of old age.

Comment: The only thing a duplicate notice is supposed to do is point people to existing answers. I don't see why it matters whether or not the the target question is closed. An open question doesn't necessarily have more or better answers and I don't see a point in *not* telling a user good answers exist just because the previous question got closed.

Comment: @nerak99 You've failed to successfully argue that a closed question can't have an answer, and therefore can't answer the duplicate question.  Saying that you think duplicates questions shouldn't be allowed to be closed as duplicates of questions that are closed doesn't in any way change the fact that they have an answer, so the text is entirely accurate.  If you don't want them to be closed as duplicates *despite* having an answer there, then you'll need to explain why you feel that's merited.

Comment: Right: I clearly misunderstand the nature of Meta-SO as I thought it was allowed to be just discussion. (After all, that is an option that I selected) Also, I was enquiring about the phenomenon as an interest, not a claim. The fact that a question   a) says "Is this a thing" i.e I gave no opinion, it just brought to mind chains in the mathematical sense 
b) is clearly not a duplicate (as some zealot would have closed it)
c) Generated an answer. Which means it must be a question that someone could answer. This makes it seem odd to me some individuals went mad witn the downvote.

Comment: [Voting is different on Meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) in that up and down votes can also be used to indicate disagreement.

Comment: Coming back to this after a long time, I am really surprised at the down votes! What is peoples problem with this as a discussion point on MetaSO?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is a thing. No, it is not a problem. Here's where you're getting tripped up

[Question #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21142686/making-a-robust-resizable-swing-chess-gui) is Too Broad. It's asking

> How would I go about making this resizable Chess GUI?

Which is another way of asking

> Can someone give me the code to do this? Pretty please?

We wholesale close those all the time. We colloquially call them "Gimme teh codez", because they tend to be poorly formatted as well. This is the [flooded car fraud](http://www.dmv.org/buy-sell/used-cars/avoiding-flood-damaged-car.php) of Too Broad. It's a higher quality of the same problem. It's not deletion worthy because it's gotten upvotes and is a nice answer.

[Question #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21077322/create-a-chess-board-with-jpanel) is **asking the same thing**. It doesn't ignore the problems, but it can be dupehammered shut faster than it could be closed as Too Broad. I have done this myself. Keep in mind that the second question can benefit from the answer of the first.

Comment: "It's not deletion worthy because it's gotten upvotes and is a nice answer." Why ain't the answers worthy of being on a good question?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Clearly downvotes and upvotes can be a mark of prejudice as well as quality.

Comment: @Braiam first a good question would have to be asked that we can merge them to.

Comment: @KevinB why can't you provide that good question? Why nobody can't do a thing that involves they spending effort into improving the site? It's easy to through up a question if you already know the answer and know what does it solve. You don't need to merge questions, you just need to ask and answer it yourself.

Comment: @Braiam Probably for the same reason you haven't.

Comment: @KevinB when I say "you", replace it with "one". And I don't because I don't know enough java to separate the wall of code into snippets.

Comment: Just to be clear, this was not a question about Java, that is just an example of a closed loop of questions.

Comment: the stack mods don't even know what they're doing any more